# print from json with a given condition in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm into the terraform world recently and learning based on the requirements. I've a question on printing the values with a given condition

json file:

```
{
    "team1" : [
        {
            "engg_name" : "Alex",
            "guid" : 1001,
            "scope" : "QA"
        },        
        {
            "engg_name" : "Trex",
            "guid" : 1002,
            "scope" : "QA"
        },        
        {
            "engg_name" : "Jessica",
            "guid" : 1003,
            "scope" : "QA"
        },
        {
            "engg_name" : "Tom",
            "guid" : 1004,
            "scope" : "DEV"
        }
    ],
    "team2" : [
        {
            "engg_name" : "Roger",
            "guid" : 2001,
            "scope" : "DEV"
        },
        {
            "engg_name" : "Jhonny",
            "guid" : 2002,
            "scope" : "DEV"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm trying:

print the **engg** whose scope is **DEV** from the json file

```
   locals {
     teams = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/teams_info.json"))
    
    engg_with_scope_dev =  flatten([for i in local.teams : i.teams if keys(local.teams).scope == "DEV"])
    
    }
```

Error:

```
    engg_with_scope_dev =  flatten([for i in local.teams : i.teams if keys(local.teams).scope == "DEV"])
    |----------------
    | local.teams is object with 2 attributes

This value does not have any attributes.
```

Can someone suggest me what's the right way to just print based on the condition?

output must be as following:

```
engg_with_scope_dev = ["Tom", "Roger", "Jhonny"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an embedded `for` loop for this:

```
locals {
  teams = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/teams_info.json"))

  engg_with_scope_dev = flatten([for team in local.teams : [
    for engineer in team : engineer.engg_name if engineer.scope == "DEV"
  ]])
}
```

Other solution would be to use a concatenation of the lists with [`ellipsis`](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments) operator:

```
locals {
  teams = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/teams_info.json"))

  engg_with_scope_dev = ([
    for engineer in concat(values(local.teams)...) : engineer.engg_name if engineer.scope == "DEV"
  ])
}
```

But also, a simple [`flatten`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/flatten) with [`values`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/values) would work as well:

```
locals {
  teams = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/teams_info.json"))

  engg_with_scope_dev = ([
    for engineer in flatten(values(local.teams)) : engineer.engg_name if engineer.scope == "DEV"
  ])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answers @Ervin.  I'm looking just to print the list of engg_name where scope = "DEV. With your approach, it prints the complete block

example: 
`
{
info = [
  {
    "engg_name" = "Tom"
    "guid" = 1004
    "scope" = "DEV"
  },
  {
    "engg_name" = "Roger"
    "guid" = 2001
    "scope" = "DEV"
  },
  {
    "engg_name" = "Jhonny"
    "guid" = 2002
    "scope" = "DEV"
  },
]
}`

Comment: aah... unfortunately, I cannot have the output in code :(

Comment: Please edit your question and specify what would you like the output to be exactly.

Comment: Sorry for it. I just updated the question

Comment: Updated my answer, all 3 of them with `engineer.engg_name if engineer.scope == "DEV"`